# combining rows/columns from spark data frames by mathematical operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have two spark data frames (A and B) with respective sizes a x m and b x m, containing floating point values.
Additionally, each data frame has a column 'ID', that is a string identifier. A and B have exactly the same set of 'ID's (i.e. contain information about the same group of customers.)

I'd like to combine a column of A with a column of B by some function.
More specifically, I'd like to build a scalar product a column of A with a column of B, with ordering of the columns according to the ID.
Even more specifically I'd like to calculate the correlation between columns of A and B.
Performing this operation on all pairs of columns would be the same as a matrix multiplication: A_transposed x B.
However, for now I'm only interested in correlations of a small subset of pairs.

I have two approaches in mind, but I struggle to implement them. (And don't know whether either is possible or advisable, at all.)

(1) Take the column of interest of each data frame and combines each entry to a key value pair, where the key is the ID. Then something like reduceByKey() on the two columns of key value pairs and subsequent summation.

(2) Take the column of interest of each data frame, sort it by its ID, cast it to an RDD (haven't figure out how to do this) and simply apply
Statistics.corr(rdd1,rdd2) from pyspark.mllib.stat.

Also I wonder: Is it generally computationally preferable to operate on columns rather than rows (since spark data frames are columnar oriented) or does that make no difference?

Comment: Do you mean you want to `equal join` the two data frames by customer ID?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be one way to achieve what I am looking for. Also with regard to this, I'd be happy if someone could comment on my very last question.

Comment: Operate on column or Operate on row is all from your requirements I think. In data analysis situation, it is often the case that tables are wide, i.e, with many columns, but when dealing with a single query, only few numbers of columns (or fields) are considered useful, perhaps this is what you mean by `prefer to operate columns`?

Comment: Say I want to calculate some statistic on a column (row) of my data set. I wonder how the data is distributed across my cluster. Can I think of it as certain columns (rows) being materialized on a certain node?
If that is the case, I'd expect my calculation to be much faster if all necessary data, i.e. the particular column (row) exists at one node. Otherwise a lot of shuffling would be necessary for the calculation. Or is the physical distribution of the data independent of the structure of the data frame?

Comment: Data are striped to rows groups and distributed across the cluster. you could think you are operating on a big table, and the table are split into many tablet which contains part of rows, and all tablet together make the whole table. When you make a query on the table, it will actually do a two steps calculation indeed, firstly, at the local node, tablet will be read out row by row, do the filter stuff, select some columns in need and save as a local file, note here in the local file, unwanted columns of your query would not even exist; the second step is to first shuffle all the local files

Comment: Thanks Yijie! Do I correctly understand that a calculation on all data from a single row (e.g. calculating the mean) would probably be fast than doing the same calculation on a single column, since the data is distributed as rows?

Comment: Yes, when no need to consider the inter-row relationship, e.g, a filter, a calculation on single row's several columns, the query performance is purely determined by the calculations of each row, but when you have inter-row relationship to consider, for instance, you want to do group by & aggregation, in order to get the right result, shuffle should be introduced and also affect the performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from spark 1.4 and if all you need is pearson correlation then you could go like this:

```
cor = dfA.join(dfB, dfA.id == dfB.id, how='inner').select(dfA.value.alias('aval'), dfB.value.alias('bval')).corr('aval', 'bval')
```